# Splash screens not working in PhoneGap Build

Tags: android, ios, splash-screen, phonegap-build

I can't get splash screens working at all, in either Android or iOS.

I'm using PhoneGap Build and I've set config.xml like this, which is for v3.0.0 now.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/3.0.0"
    id        = "myid"
    version   = "1.0.0">


<name>myname</name>

<description>
    mydesc
</description>

<author>
</author>

<preference name="permissions" value="none"/>
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" />       <!-- JB 4.0 -->
<preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />

<icon src="icon.png" />
<gap:platform name="ios" />
<gap:platform name="android" />
<gap:splash src="splash.png" gap:platform="ios" width="320" height="480" />
<gap:splash src="splash.png" gap:platform="android" width="320" height="480" />

</widget>
```

I've taken the personal info out.

The app works fine otherwise but I've never got the splash screen to work, ever, even when it was for PhoneGap 2.7.0 and 2.9.0 and just Android.

The splash.png and icon.png are actually the same image at the moment. I've tried with different ones though. I only started testing on iOS recently and the PhoneGap Build default icon only seems to come up in iOS do I decided I need to put a custom splash screen.

I cannot find an example of where or how you use the  tags, except the official docs and even there they show an example config.xml and the  tags but they don't say where to put them or if there are any other rules.

Comment: It's Gods way of telling you that splash screens are evil. http://cyrilmottier.com/2012/05/03/splash-screens-are-evil-dont-use-them/

Comment: I'd happily not use one but Phone Gap Build has a default image for one that I don't want.

Comment: So far, no success about the black screen for, any luck on your part ?

Comment: The PhoneGap Build tech support are looking into it. If/when I get an answer I'll post it here.

Comment: See my [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34783951/2252113) , It is working for cordova 4.0.0 Android Samsung S6 Edge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this issues seems to be fixed now.

As you can see from my initial question I was coding the config wrong. The PGB versions selection code should not be "xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/3.0.0" but:

```
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.0.0" />
```

I do blame PGB a bit for this as the docs weren't clear (though they are improving).

Anyway - [get your splash screens working use the info here](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_icons_and_splash.md.html#Icons%20and%20Splash%20Screens).

I'm now using PGB 3.3.0 and it seems all fine.

Comment: Please, update your answer, so link would become clickable. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**For iOS**

You will need to copy your splash screen images into the platform directory, they will not automatically be copied from `www/res/`.

For iOS this will be:

`platform/ios/[name of your project]/splash/`

These should be the PhoenGap default splashscreens.

**For Android**

The documentation seems a bit lacking for this. But you need to create the relevant folders in  your `platform/android/res` folder. These should be:

- platform/android/res/drawable-land-hdpi
- platform/android/res/drawable-land-ldpi
- platform/android/res/drawable-land-mdpi
- platform/android/res/drawable-land-xhdpi
- platform/android/res/drawable-land-xxhdpi
- platform/android/res/drawable-port-hdpi
- platform/android/res/drawable-port-ldpi
- platform/android/res/drawable-port-mdpi
- platform/android/res/drawable-port-xhdpi
- platform/android/res/drawable-port-xxhdpi

Inside those folders you will need to upload your splash screen, make sure it is called splash.png, otherwise it will not be picked up by the application.

One final and important step, you need to add the following line to your main Activity file, this can be found within your android project folder and will be named the same name as your application. The file extends the Cordova default activity file which explains about extending and adding the splash screen. The file will be:

`platforms/android/src/com/[your app name]/[your app name].java`

It should look something like this:

```
package com.your.project;

import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.cordova.*;

public class YourProject extends CordovaActivity 
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.init();
        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());
        //super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html")
    }
}
```

But needs to be changed to:

```
package com.your.project;

import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.cordova.*;

public class YourProject extends CordovaActivity 
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.init();
        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
        super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());
        //super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html")
    }
}
```

Notice the additional line added:

```
super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
```

Official documentation is here, http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/config_ref_images.md.html#Icons%20and%20Splash%20Screens, but it doesn't seem to cover all the necessary steps.

Comment: This is for Phonegap though. I'm using PhoneGap Build. It was a problem with the config.xml file.

Comment: setIntegerProperty funcation in CordovaActivity will be deprecated in 3.0 on July 2013. so how can we use this.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment below your question, here is what I recommend.

1. Create a small black square and save the image as splash.png
2. Place splash.png in your root folder (the same location as your index.html)
3. Use this in your config.xml `<gap:splash src="splash.png" />`

You will now have a solid black splash screen that will look like there is no splash screen.

Comment: I'll try that but seeing as so far no images have worked at all I don't see why that should.

Comment: I know my comment wont be that useful to you, but know that I have exactly the same problem. I build my app through build.phonegap.com, my config.xml seems ok and yet, when my app start, I get a black screen for several second and then my app launches... If i find a solution, i'll let you know.

Comment: Thanks Sephy. I'm going to delete my app and just rebuild it I think.