# Apache Cordova splash screens not showing in Android

Tags: android, cordova, splash-screen

I am running Apache Cordova 3.6.3-0.2.13. And I try to get the splash screens working. I have followed the documentation on http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.6.0/config_ref_images.md.html#Icons%20and%20Splash%20Screens. And the icons are working, but no success for the splash screens. We are also using the Ionic framework (version 1.2.8) on top of Cordova.

What I have done:

**Added icons and splash screens to config.xml from the project root:**

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="splash"/>
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000"/>
<platform name="android">
  <icon src="icons/icon.png"/>

  <!-- you can use any density that exists in the Android project -->
  <splash src="icons/android-splash-land-hdpi.png" density="land-hdpi"/>
  <splash src="icons/android-splash-land-ldpi.png" density="land-ldpi"/>
  <splash src="icons/android-splash-land-mdpi.png" density="land-mdpi"/>
  <splash src="icons/android-splash-land-xhdpi.png" density="land-xhdpi"/>

  <splash src="icons/android-splash-port-hdpi.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
  <splash src="icons/android-splash-port-ldpi.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
  <splash src="icons/android-splash-port-mdpi.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
  <splash src="icons/android-splash-port-xhdpi.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
</platform>
```

Ofcourse the `icons` directory exists and also the files are in place. When I build the project with `ionic run android` or `cordova run android`. The build process also creates the icons and splash screens into the `platforms/android/res/drawable` directory!

Also the config file located at `platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml` is correctly updated and the `<preference>` and `<icon>` and `<splash>` elements are in place.

I also tried with the `org.apache.cordova.splashscreen` plugin and also no success. I have added the plugin with `ionic plugin add org.apache.cordova.splashscreen` and also added `onDeviceReady` the code `navigator.splashscreen.show();`. But this also shows nothing.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Also note if you use Ionic also, recently they added creating icons and splashscreens from the CLI: http://ionicframework.com/blog/automating-icons-and-splash-screens/

Comment: cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-splashscreen

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Just had this problem myself. Change this

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="splash"/>
```

to

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
```

This fixed it.

source:
http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/need-help-with-displaying-splash-screen-on-android-cordova-3-6/10436/12

Comment: This works for me, but i had to install cordova-plugin-splashscreen

Comment: I can attest that you need to rename it from "splash" to "screen" in config.xml AND make sure you 'cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-splashscreen'

Comment: This works, but Cordova splash screen provides 5 to 6 different style of animation on splash screens. however, only 1 type "screen" is working correctly. and it also has different animation behavior on Android and IOS platforms.

Comment: this works but bare in mind that some people had also browser platform installation. The browser will try to reach a `hostname/screen` file. My solution was to make a specific configuration in `config.xml` for browser: `<platform name="browser">...<preference name="SplashScreen" value="assets/some-real-image.png"/>...` and leave `<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>` in root widget.

Comment: This solution doesn't works for me, even I've tried everything nothing works..ios shows splash screen but android does not :(

Answer (score 15):

I had to install the splash screen plugin to make it work

`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-splashscreen`

as well as adding

`<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />`

`<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="2000" />`

Answer (score 10):

For new comers and those who are still facing this issue

1) Add Splash screen preference in **config.xml**

```
<preference
    name="SplashScreen"
    value="screen" />
<preference
    name="AutoHideSplashScreen"
    value="true" />
<preference
    name="SplashScreenDelay"
    value="5000" />

<feature name="SplashScreen" >
    <param
        name="android-package"
        value="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen.SplashScreen" />

    <param
        name="onload"
        value="true" />
</feature>
```

2) Declare your splash screens in **config.xml**

```
    <!-- you can use any density that exists in the Android project -->
    <splash
        density="land-hdpi"
        src="res/drawable-land-hdpi/splash.png" />
    <splash
        density="land-ldpi"
        src="res/drawable-land-ldpi/splash.png" />
    <splash
        density="land-mdpi"
        src="res/drawable-land-mdpi/splash.png" />
    <splash
        density="land-xhdpi"
        src="res/drawable-land-xhdpi/splash.png" />
    <splash
        density="port-hdpi"
        src="res/drawable-hdpi/splash.png" />
    <splash
        density="port-ldpi"
        src="res/drawable-ldpi/splash.png" />
    <splash
        density="port-mdpi"
        src="res/drawable-mdpi/splash.png" />
    <splash
        density="port-xhdpi"
        src="res/drawable-xhdpi/splash.png" />
</platform>
```

3) Finally Add [this class](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/blob/master/src/android/SplashScreen.java) into your android project structure under **org.apache.cordova.splashscreen** package

or

install it as Cordova plugin.

Comment: I love full answers, my issue just was missing `  <feature name="SplashScreen" >
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen.SplashScreen" />
    <param name="onload" value="true" />
  </feature>`

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue on android, I put the Splash Screen Directly into `res/drawable-hdpi` and got the following error during cordova build.

```
res/drawable-hdpi-v4/DocBackground.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
```

When I de-capitalised the file name, in `~project/icons`, cordova build copied them to the `res/drawable` folder & splash screen worked.

Comment: That did it for me. It's a pity that not notification is given for having the files named improperly in the folder listed in config.xml.

Answer (score 2):

I'd faced same issue and I've fixed it by using following configuration :-

install splash screen plugin

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-splashscreen
```

Next we need to add following preference in config.xml,

```
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
<preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
```

Add the Splashscreen images to folders like below

```
<platform name="android">
    <splash qualifier="land-hdpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-land-hdpi.png" />
    <splash qualifier="land-ldpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-land-ldpi.png" />
    <splash qualifier="land-mdpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-land-mdpi.png" />
    <splash qualifier="land-xhdpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-land-xhdpi.png" />
    <splash qualifier="land-xxhdpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-land-xxhdpi.png" />
    <splash qualifier="land-xxxhdpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-land-xxxhdpi.png" />
    <splash qualifier="port-hdpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-port-hdpi.png" />
    <splash qualifier="port-ldpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-port-ldpi.png" />
    <splash qualifier="port-mdpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-port-mdpi.png" />
    <splash qualifier="port-xhdpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-port-xhdpi.png" />
    <splash qualifier="port-xxhdpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-port-xxhdpi.png" />
    <splash qualifier="port-xxxhdpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-port-xxxhdpi.png" />
</platform>
```

**land-ldpi is not a density but a qualifier**

**Therefore the correct each splash tag as below:**

```
<splash qualifier="land-ldpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-land-ldpi.png" />
```

After above configuration, below step is very important,

```
<platform name="android">
   <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
</platform>
```

Answer (score 1):

After carefully following the PhoneGap CLI splash screen instructions, my Android splash screen was still not showing up. I then looked at build.gradle under platforms/android and noticed that changes I made to the defaultConfig block were causing changes to AndroidManifest.xml that ultimately prevented the splash screen from working. Below is the defaultConfig block I was using:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.leadingedje"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode getAppVersionCode()
    versionName getAppVersionName()
}
```

When I removed this block from build.gradle, the splash screen started working again.

Answer (score 1):

## Splashscreen integration:

## Android

1. Add the Splashscreen images to folders like below:

   ```
   root/res/drawable-land-hdpi/screen.png
   root/res/drawable-land-ldpi/screen.png
   root/res/drawable-land-mdpi/screen.png
   root/res/drawable-land-xdpi/screen.png

   root/res/drawable-port-hdpi/screen.png
   root/res/drawable-port-ldpi/screen.png
   root/res/drawable-port-mdpi/screen.png
   root/res/drawable-port-xdpi/screen.png
   ```
2. Add splash Screen plugin to android project.
   (git : git://git.apache.org/cordova-plugin-splashscreen.git)

   ```
   src/org/apache/cordova/splashscreen/SplashScreen.java
   ```
3. Add plugin javascript file in assets/www/js/lib/android/plugins/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/www/
   (git : https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/blob/master/www/splashscreen.js)
4. Add plugin entery in cordova_plugins.js

   ```
   {
       "file": "plugins/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/www/splashscreen.js",
       "id": "cordova-plugin-splashscreen.SplashScreen",
       "clobbers": [
           "navigator.splashscreen"
       ]
   },


   "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "3.1.0",..
   ```
5. Add following code in config.xml

   ```
   <preference name="SplashScreen"         value="screen"/>
   <preference name="SplashScreenDelay"    value="5000" />
   <feature name="SplashScreen">
       <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen.SplashScreen" />
       <param name="onload" value="true" />
   </feature>
   ```
6. now build the android project.

Answer (score 1):

2019 February end:

Only two things I did and it worked:

- Install plugin:

  `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-splashscreen`
- Add below to config.xml, have corresponding images

(1st splash line is a generic screen size, if you want)

```
<platform name="android">
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-2732x2732.png" />

    <splash density="land-ldpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-land-320x200-ldpi.png" />
    <splash density="land-mdpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-land-480x320-mdpi.png" />
    <splash density="land-hdpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-land-800x480-hdpi.png" />
    <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-land-1280x720-xhdpi.png" />
    <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-land-1600x960-xxhdpi.png" />
    <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-land-1920x1280-xxxhdpi.png" />
    <splash density="port-ldpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-port-200x320-ldpi.png" />
    <splash density="port-mdpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-port-320x480-mdpi.png" />
    <splash density="port-hdpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-port-480x800-hdpi.png" />
    <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-port-720x1280-xhdpi.png" />
    <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-port-960x1600-xxhdpi.png" />
    <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-port-1280x1920-xxxhdpi.png" />
</platform>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding default splash tag

Add this to config.xml in the root destination or in www/config.xml

```
<gap:splash src="splash.png" />
```

Comment: PhoneGap != Apache Cordova