# How to get Splash screen in Cordova CLI project

Tags: cordova, command-line-interface, config, splash-screen

I am trying to get splash screen in my Cordova project. My first target is Android. I followed [http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/config_ref_images.md.html] and made the below entries in my config.xml

```
<platform name="android">

<splash src="res/screen/android/splash-land-hdpi.png" density="land-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-land-ldpi.png" density="land-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-land-mdpi.png" density="land-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-land-xhdpi.png" density="land-xhdpi"/>

    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-port-hdpi.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-port-ldpi.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-port-mdpi.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-port-xhdpi.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
</platform>
```

And the folder structre is ,

[image]

I also followed [http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_splashscreen_splashscreen.md.html] Added splash screen plugin into the project. But when I launch the project, it didn't show the splash screen.

What can be the problem. Why cordova is making simple things tough ?

Comment: which plugin is installed?.

Comment: The plugin I installed is  org.apache.cordova.splashscreen 1.0.0 "Splashscreen"

Comment: Similar question is already asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26426981/apache-cordova-splash-screens-not-showing-in-android?rq=1

Comment: I should have seen this and I don't know how I missed that. That worked. Many Thanks.