# PhoneGap Build: icons and splashscreens are not displayed correctly

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-build

I have the problem that android and ios icons are not included correctly when I build the app with Phonegap Build.

The config.xml part is as follows:

```
<icon src="www/res/icon/icon.png" />
<splash src="www/res/screen/splash.jpg" />

<platform name="android">
    <icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-ldpi.png" density="ldpi" />
    <icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-mdpi.png" density="mdpi" />
    <icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-hdpi.png" density="hdpi" />
    <icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-xhdpi.png" density="xhdpi" />

    <splash gap:qualifier="port-hdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-port.png" width="480" height="800" />
    <splash gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-port.png" width="640" height="960" />
    <splash gap:qualifier="land-hdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-land.jpg" width="800" height="480" />
    <splash gap:qualifier="land-xhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-land.jpg" width="960" height="640" />
</platform>

<platform name="ios">
    <!-- iOS 7.0+ -->
    <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch  -->
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-60.png" width="60" height="60" />
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" height="120" />
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" height="180" />
    <!-- iPad -->
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-76.png" width="76" height="76" />
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" height="152" />
    <!-- iOS 6.1 -->
    <!-- Spotlight Icon -->
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-40.png" width="40" height="40" />
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" height="80" />
    <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch -->
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon.png" width="57" height="57" />
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon@2x.png" width="114" height="114" />
    <!-- iPad -->
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" height="72" />
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" height="144" />
    <!-- iPhone Spotlight and Settings Icon -->
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-small.png" width="29" height="29" />
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" height="58" />
    <!-- iPad Spotlight and Settings Icon -->
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-50.png" width="50" height="50" />
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" height="100" />

    <!-- Splash sreens -->
    <splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" height="960" width="640" />
    <splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-landscape-2x.jpg" height="640" width="960" />
    <splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-568h-2x.png" height="1136" width="640" />
    <splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-landscape-568h-2x.jpg" height="640" width="1136" />
    <splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" height="1024" width="768" />
    <splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.jpg" height="768" width="1024" />
</platform>

<platform name="wp8">
    <icon src="www/res/icon/wp/ApplicationIcon.png" width="99" height="99" />
    <!-- tile image -->
    <icon src="www/res/icon/wp/Background.png" width="159" height="159" />  
    <splash src="www/res/screen/wp/SplashScreenImage.png" width="768" height="1280"/>
</platform>
```

The files do exist in said folders, they even show up inside the apk and ipa in `assets/www/res` and `payload/myApp.app/www/res`, respectively. But phonegap build does not copy them to `res/drawable-*` or `payload/myApp.app`. Instead, it uses the default icons and splashscreens (the [Cordova bot](http://cordova.apache.org/images/cordova_bot.png) in Android and transparent images in iOS).

The WP8 build, which is done locally, works like a charm.
I already deleted the app in Phonegap Build and created it anew, but no icon changed, only the app id is a bit higher now.

Do I have to put the icons in a special location, or is there a problem in config.xml?

Update: I just looked into the debug output of iOS build. Some PNGs are copied around, but the ipa still contains the transparent icons in `Payload\MyApp.app`. Example copy log:

```
CopyPNGFile build/MyApp.app/icon-76.png MyApp/Resources/icons/icon-76.png
    cd /project
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/copypng -compress /project/MyApp/Resources/icons/icon-76.png /project/build/MyApp.app/icon-76.png
```

The same goes for android:

```
[crunch] Processing image to cache: /project/res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png => /project/bin/res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png
[crunch]   (processed image to cache entry /project/bin/res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png: 67% size of source)
```

Well, I did define other directories/files in config.xml!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax shown in the question is the syntax for local Cordova.

It seems that Phonegap Build service does not use the same syntax. Phonegap Build works fine if you stick really close to [the Phonegap Build docs](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_icons_and_splash.md.html), using the `gap:platform` attribute instead of nesting your icons into `platform` tags.

Answer (score 1):

I have had some issues with SplashScreen as well, see next answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26427769/1800695

Add next to `config.xml`:

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
```

Also these are the entries in my `config.xml` for icons and splash screens (Android only):

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
<platform name="android">
    <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
    <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
</platform>
<icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
```

Also this NPM package might be of any interest: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-media-generator

Comment: I will definitely try that, once the problem with the icons is solved and the icon solution failed to solve the splashscreen prob as well.

Comment: I updated answer with my icon and splash settings hope it helps.

Comment: It works with a local Cordova project. So it should also work with PhoneGap I suppose

Answer (score 0):

try keep up with documentation.. density is declared in the **end.exmpl**:

```
<platform name="android">
        <splash src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-landscape.png" density="land-hdpi" />
        <splash src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-landscape.png" density="land-ldpi" />
        <splash src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-landscape.png" density="land-mdpi" />
        <splash src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-landscape.png" density="land-xhdpi" />

        <splash src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" density="port-hdpi" />
        <splash src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" density="port-ldpi" />
        <splash src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" density="port-mdpi" />
        <splash src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" density="port-xhdpi" />
</platform>
```

This is part of my working config.xml,

---

also src souldnt be "**www**/.../..." due to error while building process, only the root project folder. Way to see if the build is passed how is should in platforms/android/res/**multipleFolders**--> folders that should be full with screensplash img which are not added manualy by you.