# Phonegap Splashscreen

Tags: cordova

I'm trying to start a phonegap app, but I can't get to make the splash screen work.

I just created the app with **"phonegap create my-app"**

Installed the plugin: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen

then I added the following lines to the config.xml in the root of project:

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="4000" />
<gap:splash src="splash.png" />
```

but it wont work.

also tryied to add

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
          function onDeviceReady() {
            navigator.splashscreen.show();
        }
        </script>
```

in index.html but no luck.

any help?

***UPDATE:***

I got it to work.
Had to start from the beggining.

It ended like this:

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="pt.some" version="0.1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
    <name>Sample APP</name>
    <description>
        Description
    </description>
    <author email="some@some.com" href="http://google.com/">
        author
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <preference name="permissions" value="none" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="default" />
    <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
    <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
    <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />
    <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" />
    <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
    <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
    <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="10" />
    <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.battery-status" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media-capture" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.console" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.contacts" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-motion" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.globalization" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration" />
    <icon src="icon.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="ldpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="mdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="hdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="blackberry" src="www/res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover" src="www/res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="57" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-57.png" width="57" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="72" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="114" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png" width="114" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="144" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png" width="144" />
    <icon gap:platform="webos" src="www/res/icon/webos/icon-64.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="winphone" src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="winphone" gap:role="background" src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/icon-173-tile.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi" src="www/res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-mdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-hdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="blackberry" src="www/res/screen/blackberry/screen-225.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="480" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" width="320" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="960" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" width="640" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="1136" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-568h-2x.png" width="640" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="1024" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" width="768" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="768" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" width="1024" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="winphone" src="www/res/screen/windows-phone/screen-portrait.jpg" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
    <engine name="android" spec="^4.0.0" />
</widget>
```

And also nothing added in index.html and it worked :)

Comment: what version of cordova and platform are you using?

Comment: Cordova is 5.0.0 and plataform is android.
I installed everything today. "phonegap -v" is 5.0.0-0.28.1

Comment: I know this may be trivial, but you've included the `cordova.js` file in your pages markup right?

Comment: yes. it is there since the begin since this is the template app of phonegap

Answer (score 0):

Change the line:

```
<gap:splash src="splash.png" />
```

To:

```
<gap:splash src="screen.png" />
```

This solved my issue with Cordova CLI, so maybe the same solves the PhoneGap issue, see [Apache Cordova splash screens not showing in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26426981/apache-cordova-splash-screens-not-showing-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure for which platform you are building..
It has to go by platform, here is the proper node for android:

```
<platform name="android">
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-land-hdpi.png" density="land-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-land-ldpi.png" density="land-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-land-mdpi.png" density="land-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-land-xhdpi.png" density="land-xhdpi"/> 
</platform>
```

Comment: Where are you images located?

Comment: Consider updating android platform to 4.0.2 (I see you're at 4.0.0). See http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2015/05/26/android-402.html