# Apache Cordova custom splash screen not visible in Android and ios

Tags: android, ios, angular, cordova, splash-screen

I am running Apache Cordova 8.1.2 along with Angular 7 project. I have installed `SplashScreen` plugin and changed my config.xml as stated in [this documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/8.x/reference/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/index.html).
Here is my config.xml

```
<platform name="android">
        <icon density="ldpi" src="projects/cys-mobile-app/src/assets/img/android/display-icon/ldpi.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="projects/cys-mobile-app/src/assets/img/android/display-icon/mdpi.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="projects/cys-mobile-app/src/assets/img/android/display-icon/hdpi.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="projects/cys-mobile-app/src/assets/img/android/display-icon/xhdpi.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="projects/cys-mobile-app/src/assets/img/android/display-icon/xxhdpi.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="projects/cys-mobile-app/src/assets/img/android/display-icon/xxxhdpi.png" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="projects/cys-mobile-app/src/assets/img/android/splash-screen/splash-land-hdpi.png" />
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="projects/cys-mobile-app/src/assets/img/android/splash-screen/splash-land-ldpi.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="projects/cys-mobile-app/src/assets/img/android/splash-screen/splash-land-mdpi.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="projects/cys-mobile-app/src/assets/img/android/splash-screen/splash-land-xhdpi.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="projects/cys-mobile-app/src/assets/img/android/splash-screen/splash-land-xxhdpi.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="projects/cys-mobile-app/src/assets/img/android/splash-screen/splash-land-xxxhdpi.png" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <splash src="projects/cys-mobile-app/src/assets/img/ios/splash-screen/splash-2732.png" />
        <icon height="180" src="projects/cys-mobile-app/src/assets/img/ios/Icon-App-60x60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="60" src="projects/cys-mobile-app/src/assets/img/ios/Icon-App-60x60@2x.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" src="projects/cys-mobile-app/src/assets/img/ios/Icon-App-60x60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="76" src="projects/cys-mobile-app/src/assets/img/ios/Icon-App-76x76@1x.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" src="projects/cys-mobile-app/src/assets/img/ios/Icon-App-76x76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="40" src="projects/cys-mobile-app/src/assets/img/ios/Icon-App-40x40@1x.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" src="projects/cys-mobile-app/src/assets/img/ios/Icon-App-40x40@2x.png" width="80" />
    </platform>
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^5.0.2" />
```

With the above code I can see default cordova splash screen in `ios` and a black screen with a spinner in center in `Android`.
Icons are working fine, but no success for the splash screens. I want a custom image which I have provided in splash tag should be visible as splash screen.

I also tried all the solutions given in : [Apache Cordova splash screens not showing in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26426981/apache-cordova-splash-screens-not-showing-in-android).

Also all the image files are in place. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you do not have any portrait splash screens listed for android, and for iOS you do not have any listed. In the android section you want to add:

```
<splash density="port-mdpi" src="projects/cys-mobile-app/src/assets/img/android/splash-screen/splash1.png" />
<splash density="port-hdpi" src="projects/cys-mobile-app/src/assets/img/android/splash-screen/splash2.png" />
...
```

For iOS you need to add them like so:

```
<splash height="480" src="projects/cys-mobile-app/src/assets/img/android/splash-screen/splash1.png" width="320" />
<splash height="960" src="projects/cys-mobile-app/src/assets/img/android/splash-screen/splash2.png" width="640" />
...
```

Here you need to identify all portrait and landscape configurations for the height and width properties.